# g:each in a table

Tags: grails, groovy

Hi i'm using groovy & grails. trying to loop in a table. Getting error at start of g each

```
<table class='display'>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>IATA</th>
    <th>STATE</th>
    <th>COUNTRY</th>

  </tr>

  <g:each in="${airportsInstanceList}" var="book">
    <tr>
      <td>${airports.id}</td>
      <td>${fieldValue(bean: airports, field: "name")}</td>
      <td>${airports.iata}</td>
      <td>${airports.state}</td>
      <td>${airports.country}</td>
<!--      <td><g:link action="show" id="${airports.id}">details</g:link></td>-->

    </tr>
  </g:each>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var` attribute is the name of the iteration variable.  Change that from `book` to `airports`.  Changing `airports` to `airport` would make more sense, too, although that's just an issue of style.