# How to generate table dynamically in grails?

Tags: grails, controller, view

I need to display list of servers running up on ec2. I am able to display them in the page row by row without any columns, however I need to display them in a table where the server name is in one column, the instance id is in the other column and so on.I have managed to extract the required fields and put them in a variables. Now I need to populate the column using the variable. I used the following code I found online to display the entire server info row by row (This is displaying all the server fields in one row). I also need to generate button in the last column for all the servers.

```
            <%
            def counter = 0

            for (i in items) {
                counter = counter + 1

                println("<td>" + i + "</td>" + "\n")

                if (counter == 1) {
                    println("</tr><tr>")
                    counter = 0
                }
            }

        %>
```

Items is the variable I am returning from my controller. I am not using any model classes.

Comment: See this questin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198003/geach-in-a-table

Comment: Wouldn't that require me to use model class?

Comment: No, any collection you want.

Comment: So the example you directed me to has airportinstancelist, so I can make a collection of serverlist in my controller class then right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming items is a collection of classes and the classes have fields representing the data you need something like the following should work.

```
<table>
<tr> <td> column one</td> <td> column two</td> </tr>
<%
        for (i in items) {
            println """<tr>  <td>${i.field1}</td> <td>${i.field2}</td> </tr>"""
        }
    %>
</table>
```

Comment: Ya i could use that one, but how would I put button in the last column?